# Protractor + Firefox + docker: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process

Tags: firefox, protractor, geckodriver, gecko

I used to work but since a week, my angular E2E tests fail to start when running in docker. It still works OK if I run them directly though.

`protractor.conf.js`

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
      args: [
        '--headless'
      ]
    }
  }
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  ...
}
```

If I start webdriver: `webdriver-manager start`

Then protractor: `protractor protractor.conf.js`

Output:

```
I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
I/direct - Using FirefoxDriver directly...
E/launcher - invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
E/launcher - WebDriverError: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/index.js:521:41)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:105:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/tmp/e2e-test/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

I've tried with both Firefox 62.0 and 60.0.2 without changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tracking down each software new releases, I finally found that gecko-driver has been received a [new v0.22.0 release](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.22.0) 4 days ago, which seems to break protractor/selenium.

For now, I'll force v0.21.0 of geckodriver which works just fine:

```
webdriver-manager update  --versions.gecko=v0.21.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, [running Firefox in headless mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode) solved the issue.